# The proof of inequality

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

How to prove that $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (\frac{a_1+a_2+\dots+a_k}{k})-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n a_k^2\leq \frac{n}{2}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{4k}?$$
In my book it is said that this comes from Cauchy-Schwartz inequality and  from that $$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (\frac{a_1+a_2+\dots+a_k}{k})\leq (2n-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k})^\frac{1}{2}(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2)^\frac{1}{2},$$ but I don't know how.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this inequality from?

Comment: @Toby Mak From book on dynamic programming by Bellman

Comment: Interesting inequality. But as it stands it's a mere PSQ (Problem Statement Question), hence I would vote for closing.

Comment: @user2661923 k goes from 1 to n

Comment: @user2661923 Your counterexample is not good, k is index that goes from 1 to n and in your "counterexample" is n<k

Comment: @alans good point - my blindness.

Comment: It may be useful to play around with *Summation by Parts*. This often helps with inequalities of this type. A useful resource is https://brilliant.org/wiki/summation-by-parts/, but many others exist.

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. In particular, don't just post a question as if you don't know where to start. The standard place to start is to look at your notes or book to see if there are related questions with worked solutions. Did you do this?

Comment: @user1729 I edited question. I looked in my notes, but I still don't know how to prove it, that is reason why I'm looking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $A=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2\right)^\tfrac{1}{2}$ and $M=\left(2n-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}\right)^\tfrac{1}{2}$. Since we are given
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{a_1+a_2+\dots+a_k}{k}\right)\le MA,$$
it suffices to show
$$MA-A^2\le  \frac{n}{2}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{4k}=\frac{M^2}4,$$
which is equivalent to an inequality
$$0\le\left(\frac {M}2-A\right)^2.$$